# Git clone into current directory of a new PC with same files locally than on remote repository

Tags: git, bash

I have files both locally (on new PC) and on a github repository and I want to clone/create a local repository on that PC.

I already did thess steps :

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/sebastien/.git/
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/xxxxx/yyyyyyyy
$ git pull origin master
remote: Counting objects: 791, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (615/615), done.
remote: Total 791 (delta 148), reused 743 (delta 102), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (791/791), 2.04 MiB | 323.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (148/148), done.
From https://github.com/xxxxx/yyyyyyyy
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
error: Untracked working tree file '.initBash/.AV_functions' would be overwritten by merge.
$ echo $?
128
$ git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
fatal: branch 'master' does not exist
$ echo $?
128
```

EDIT 1: The local files can be the same or older than those on the remote repo.

Can you help ?

Comment: Seems the folder where you init the repository is not empty. There are files that also exist in the repository you are cloning.

Comment: You created a local repository with `git init`, but haven't actually added any files to it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> error: Untracked working tree file '.initBash/.AV_functions' would be overwritten by merge.

Your local file's would be overwritten. So, to solve the problem you can commit your local files before pull the remote `master`.

> fatal: branch 'master' does not exist

You have no local `master`so, this error.

**Follow the instructions:**

First, cleanup your git history. I prefer to delete the `.git` folder then generate again.

```
$ rm -rf .git
$ git init
```

Commit your local files/changes.

```
$ git add -A
$ git commit -m 'message'
```

Add a new remote `origin` with remote repo's URL.

```
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/xxxxx/yyyyyyyy
```

Pull the remote `master` branch changes.

```
$ git pull origin master
```

If Conflicts occurs, then solve it. Done.

---

**Alternate:** If new PC's local changes are not important and you want to **reset** your local with remote `master` then follow it:

```
$ git init
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/xxxxx/yyyyyyyy

$ git fetch
$ git reset --hard origin/master      # local changes = origin/master changes
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is, are the local copies of the files different from the versions in the remote repo?  and if so, what do you want to do with them?

If they aren't different, you can just delete them and clone the repo.  (Cloning the repo necessarily copies the files from the remote anyway.)

```
git clone url/of/remote/repo
```

If the local files are different, and you don't want to discard the differences, then you need to decide where in history they belong.  This may depend on how this version of the files came to be in the first place.

Simplest example: The files were copies of the latest version (on some branch) in the repo.  Then perhaps they just represent updates to be pushed to that branch.  So clone the repo as above, then copy the local files over the work tree and use that as the basis for a new commit.

Or maybe they're modified versions of an *older* commit in the repo?  Then you could create a new branch, starting from that older commit, and go from there.  (Cone the repo, check out the older commit, create and checkout a new branch, *then* copy the local versions over the work tree.)

You *could* commit the local copies first (as suggested in another answer), but depending on your git version you may have to give special options to get git to accept the unrelated histories, and when you do you'll likely get conflicts on just about everything bc git will see that two unrelated change lines independently created each of the files in question.

Comment: The local files can be the same or older than those on the remote repo.